# Converting string to date in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have column in data.frame with dates in following string format (related to monthly, quarterly and annual data):

```
"2008Q1", "2008M1", "2008M2", "2008M3", "2008Q2", "2008M4", "2008M5", 
"2008M6", "2008Q3", "2008M7", "2008M8", "2008M9", "2008Q4", "2008M10", 
"2008M11", "2008M12", "2009", "2009Q1", "2009M1", "2009M2", "2009M3", 
"2009Q2", "2009M4", "2009M5", "2009M6", "2009Q3", "2009M7", "2009M8", 
"2009M9", "2009Q4", "2009M10", "2009M11", "2009M12", "2010"
```

Is there any elegant and fast solution (data.frame is really big) to convert it into two separate colums, containing frequency and the date, like this:

```
DFreq       Date
Quarterly   1/3/2008
Monthly     1/1/2008
Monthly     1/2/2008
Monthly     1/3/2008
...
Monthly     1/12/2008
Annual      1/12/2009
```

Comment: Looks like the input example and the description is not matching

Comment: Can you you `dput` a subset of your string? Something like `dput(df$date[1:5])`?

Comment: added example of data

Comment: It looks like there is no way to do this without loop with manual spliting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frequency can be extracted with a little regex, and the strings can be parsed to dates with `anytime::anydate` (which inserts "01" for missing date components), but it parses all non-year numbers as months, so a little cleanup is necessary. In tidyverse grammar,

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data_frame(date = c("2008Q1", "2008M1", "2008M2", "2008M3", "2008Q2", "2008M4", "2008M5", 
                          "2008M6", "2008Q3", "2008M7", "2008M8", "2008M9", "2008Q4", "2008M10", 
                          "2008M11", "2008M12", "2009", "2009Q1", "2009M1", "2009M2", "2009M3", 
                          "2009Q2", "2009M4", "2009M5", "2009M6", "2009Q3", "2009M7", "2009M8", 
                          "2009M9", "2009Q4", "2009M10", "2009M11", "2009M12", "2010"))

df %>% 
    mutate(frequency = recode(gsub('\\d', '', date),    # remove all numbers...
                              'M' = 'Monthly',    ...and recode as words
                              'Q' = 'Quarterly', 
                              .default = 'Annually'),
           date = anytime::anydate(date),    # parse to year-month
           date = {month(date) <- month(date) * recode(frequency,    # ...and correct the month
                                                       'Annually' = 12, 
                                                       'Quarterly' = 3, 
                                                       .default = 1); 
                   date})
#> # A tibble: 34 x 2
#>          date frequency
#>        <date>     <chr>
#>  1 2008-03-01 Quarterly
#>  2 2008-01-01   Monthly
#>  3 2008-02-01   Monthly
#>  4 2008-03-01   Monthly
#>  5 2008-06-01 Quarterly
#>  6 2008-04-01   Monthly
#>  7 2008-05-01   Monthly
#>  8 2008-06-01   Monthly
#>  9 2008-09-01 Quarterly
#> 10 2008-07-01   Monthly
#> # ... with 24 more rows
```

This approach moves adjusts appropriately so as to change quarterly and annual data so that the dates line up with the first day of the last month of the period, as the desired result in the question does. Generally, it's actually much more useful to store the first day of the period, which you can obtain by leveraging the extreme versatility of `lubridate::parse_date_time` to build a proper parser for the mixed format:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(frequency = recode(gsub('\\d', '', date),
                              'M' = 'Monthly', 
                              'Q' = 'Quarterly', 
                              .default = 'Annually'),
           date = as_date(parse_date_time(
               date, 
               c('Ym', 'Yq', 'Y'),    # possible formats
               select_formats = function(dates){    # function to determine format
                   recode(gsub('\\%.[a-z]?', '', names(dates)), 
                          'M' = '%YM%m', 
                          'Q' = '%YQ%q', 
                          .default = '%Y')
               })))
#> # A tibble: 34 x 2
#>          date frequency
#>        <date>     <chr>
#>  1 2008-01-01 Quarterly
#>  2 2008-01-01   Monthly
#>  3 2008-02-01   Monthly
#>  4 2008-03-01   Monthly
#>  5 2008-04-01 Quarterly
#>  6 2008-04-01   Monthly
#>  7 2008-05-01   Monthly
#>  8 2008-06-01   Monthly
#>  9 2008-07-01 Quarterly
#> 10 2008-07-01   Monthly
#> # ... with 24 more rows
```

Comment: Very nice solution! +1

Comment: OP seems to convert quarters to dates with the last month of the quarter (e.g. `2008Q1` ~~> `1/3/2008`)

Comment: Hm, seems inadvisable, but it's possible to add 2 months to quarters and 11 months to years after the fact.

Comment: _If_ you choose the _first_ month of the quarter (`2008Q1` ~~> `2008-01-01`), shouldn't then `2008Q2` be represented as `2008-04-01` (not `2008-02-01`). Well well, I guess OP could have been clearer here ;)

Comment: Oh crap, you're right, this isn't working like I thought. Deleting so as not to confuse...

Comment: Fixed and undeleted.

Comment: Thank you very much for such elegant solution! Why first date of the period is more preferable way to store the date?

Comment: Because otherwise monthly values will be at the beginning of the period, but quarterly and annual ones will be in the middle, a month from the end, which means you can't do useful comparisons (e.g. `>=`). The last day (i.e. the last day of the last month) of the period can also be useful, but is more work to use.

Answer (score 1):

I won't speak to the efficiency of this, but it gets the job done.

```
library(stringr)

format_to_date <- function(x){
  year <- str_extract(x, "^\\d{4}")
  if (grepl("M", x)) {
    month <- str_pad(str_extract(x, "\\d{1,2}$"), width = 2)
    paste0(year, "-", month, "-01")
  } else if (grepl("Q", x)) {
    month <- as.numeric(str_extract(x, "\\d{1}$"))
    month <- 1 + (month - 1) * 3
    paste0(year, "-", month, "-01")
  } else{
    paste0(year, "-01-01")
  }
}

Dframe <- 
  data.frame(string = c("2008M5", "2009Q3", "2011"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

as.Date(vapply(Dframe$string, format_to_date, character(1)))
```

#### Efficiency

Because I was curious, I ran these all through `microbenchmark` and came up with

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  benjamin 432.43466 433.31058 439.30987 439.20125 444.05267 448.95130    10
   pogibas 665.64618 718.50771 734.78987 745.73741 747.14000 767.26852    10
 alistaire  16.85593  17.13333  17.35033  17.31104  17.52041  17.92627    10
```

So I'd say go with @alistaire's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution similar to [**Benjamin's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46368130/1286528) (I'm using `if/else` to grep Quarters or Months) and `paste0` to get wanted format.

```
convertDate <- function(x) {
    DFreq <- "Annual"
    Date <- paste0("1/12/", x)
    foo <- unlist(strsplit(x, "[A-Z]"))
    if (length(grep("Q", x)) == 1) {
        DFreq <- "Quarterly"
        Date <- paste0("1/", as.numeric(foo[2]) * 3, "/", foo[1])
    } else if (length(grep("M", x)) == 1) {
        DFreq <- "Monthly"
        Date <- paste0("1/", foo[2], "/", foo[1])
    }
    return(data.frame(DFreq, Date))
}

INPUT <- c("2008M5", "2009Q3", "2011")
res <- sapply(INPUT, convertDate, simplify = FALSE)
do.call("rbind", res)

           DFreq      Date
2008M5   Monthly  1/5/2008
2009Q3 Quarterly  1/9/2009
2011      Annual 1/12/2011
```